# Flexbox with sticky/fixed header and bottom-sticky footer (cross platform compatible)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want a fixed header, that's at the top of the page all the time. I also want the footer to be sticky if there's not enough content to fill up the page, but it should be after the content if there is. Essentially it should behave like this https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/, but with a sticky header.

I've been messing around with this for a couple of hours now and can figure it out. Here's what I've got so far:

```css
html {
        background: black;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background: yellow;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    header {
        height: 50px;
        background: red;
    }
    
    #main {
        flex: 1;
        justify-content: stretch;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: green;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    #content {
        flex: 1;
    }
    
    footer {
        flex: none;
        height: 50px;
        background: blue;
    }
    
    p.toggle2 { /* rename toggle to anything else to get full-height content */
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
 <body>
        <header>fixed header</header>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget vestibulum augue. Pellentesque suscipit tellus quis dapibus fermentum. Sed risus lectus, mollis quis orci vitae, mattis consequat sapien. Sed vitae cursus nisi. Suspendisse cursus felis nec felis ornare, sit amet ullamcorper diam dictum. Fusce feugiat pellentesque lorem, at eleifend tellus rutrum sit amet. Vestibulum id neque est. Duis interdum nunc nec lobortis rutrum. Sed ut tincidunt turpis, et adipiscing urna. Nam sit amet tellus et elit fringilla tempus ut vitae erat. Integer eu placerat magna, non ornare felis. Aenean eu dapibus leo. Cras dui nisi, volutpat in pretium vitae, ultrices a dui. Nullam consequat feugiat purus non vehicula. Aenean lacinia, mi non euismod malesuada, lorem dolor scelerisque velit, sed consequat ante leo quis nisl. Etiam vel lacus dolor. Quisque at fringilla eros. Vivamus eget turpis sem. Praesent vel hendrerit ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer scelerisque diam ut justo feugiat, quis porttitor felis imperdiet. Mauris at ullamcorper sem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus ultrices leo vitae lacinia vulputate. Vestibulum orci ligula, imperdiet non luctus eget, luctus eu nisl. Maecenas mollis eleifend sollicitudin. Praesent dictum tristique ipsum, quis imperdiet quam. Praesent euismod velit sed ipsum posuere vulputate. Praesent placerat ipsum sed neque viverra, sed adipiscing tortor pulvinar. Phasellus blandit sit amet ligula quis ultrices. Integer tempus risus sit amet aliquam lacinia. Phasellus nec nibh vitae odio tristique commodo. Proin mollis iaculis sapien, a vestibulum odio tincidunt facilisis. Vestibulum sed nibh ornare, mattis ligula quis, porttitor magna. Duis interdum mattis mauris, vel molestie massa porta sit amet. Maecenas vel urna et nisl sodales volutpat non sed urna. Nam dui tortor, semper sed dictum non, congue quis leo. Aenean vitae mi bibendum, sollicitudin sem et, laoreet massa. Nulla ornare augue velit, non placerat nulla pretium et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non rutrum neque, ac ultrices sapien. Etiam lacinia libero vitae dolor ullamcorper laoreet. Ph sellus at auctor leo. Sed blandit urna non justo ornare blandit.</p>
                <p class="toggle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget vestibulum augue. Pellentesque suscipit tellus quis dapibus fermentum. Sed risus lectus, mollis quis orci vitae, mattis consequat sapien. Sed vitae cursus nisi. Suspendisse cursus felis nec felis ornare, sit amet ullamcorper diam dictum. Fusce feugiat pellentesque lorem, at eleifend tellus rutrum sit amet. Vestibulum id neque est. Duis interdum nunc nec lobortis rutrum. Sed ut tincidunt turpis, et adipiscing urna. Nam sit amet tellus et elit fringilla tempus ut vitae erat. Integer eu placerat magna, non ornare felis. Aenean eu dapibus leo. Cras dui nisi, volutpat in pretium vitae, ultrices a dui. Nullam consequat feugiat purus non vehicula. Aenean lacinia, mi non euismod malesuada, lorem dolor scelerisque velit, sed consequat ante leo quis nisl. Etiam vel lacus dolor. Quisque at fringilla eros. Vivamus eget turpis sem. Praesent vel hendrerit ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer scelerisque diam ut justo feugiat, quis porttitor felis imperdiet. Mauris at ullamcorper sem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus ultrices leo vitae lacinia vulputate. Vestibulum orci ligula, imperdiet non luctus eget, luctus eu nisl. Maecenas mollis eleifend sollicitudin. Praesent dictum tristique ipsum, quis imperdiet quam. Praesent euismod velit sed ipsum posuere vulputate. Praesent placerat ipsum sed neque viverra, sed adipiscing tortor pulvinar. Phasellus blandit sit amet ligula quis ultrices. Integer tempus risus sit amet aliquam lacinia. Phasellus nec nibh vitae odio tristique commodo. Proin mollis iaculis sapien, a vestibulum odio tincidunt facilisis. Vestibulum sed nibh ornare, mattis ligula quis, porttitor magna. Duis interdum mattis mauris, vel molestie massa porta sit amet. Maecenas vel urna et nisl sodales volutpat non sed urna. Nam dui tortor, semper sed dictum non, congue quis leo. Aenean vitae mi bibendum, sollicitudin sem et, laoreet massa. Nulla ornare augue velit, non placerat nulla pretium et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non rutrum neque, ac ultrices sapien. Etiam lacinia libero vitae dolor ullamcorper laoreet. Ph sellus at auctor leo. Sed blandit urna non justo ornare blandit.</p>
                <p class="toggle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget vestibulum augue. Pellentesque suscipit tellus quis dapibus fermentum. Sed risus lectus, mollis quis orci vitae, mattis consequat sapien. Sed vitae cursus nisi. Suspendisse cursus felis nec felis ornare, sit amet ullamcorper diam dictum. Fusce feugiat pellentesque lorem, at eleifend tellus rutrum sit amet. Vestibulum id neque est. Duis interdum nunc nec lobortis rutrum. Sed ut tincidunt turpis, et adipiscing urna. Nam sit amet tellus et elit fringilla tempus ut vitae erat. Integer eu placerat magna, non ornare felis. Aenean eu dapibus leo. Cras dui nisi, volutpat in pretium vitae, ultrices a dui. Nullam consequat feugiat purus non vehicula. Aenean lacinia, mi non euismod malesuada, lorem dolor scelerisque velit, sed consequat ante leo quis nisl. Etiam vel lacus dolor. Quisque at fringilla eros. Vivamus eget turpis sem. Praesent vel hendrerit ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer scelerisque diam ut justo feugiat, quis porttitor felis imperdiet. Mauris at ullamcorper sem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus ultrices leo vitae lacinia vulputate. Vestibulum orci ligula, imperdiet non luctus eget, luctus eu nisl. Maecenas mollis eleifend sollicitudin. Praesent dictum tristique ipsum, quis imperdiet quam. Praesent euismod velit sed ipsum posuere vulputate. Praesent placerat ipsum sed neque viverra, sed adipiscing tortor pulvinar. Phasellus blandit sit amet ligula quis ultrices. Integer tempus risus sit amet aliquam lacinia. Phasellus nec nibh vitae odio tristique commodo. Proin mollis iaculis sapien, a vestibulum odio tincidunt facilisis. Vestibulum sed nibh ornare, mattis ligula quis, porttitor magna. Duis interdum mattis mauris, vel molestie massa porta sit amet. Maecenas vel urna et nisl sodales volutpat non sed urna. Nam dui tortor, semper sed dictum non, congue quis leo. Aenean vitae mi bibendum, sollicitudin sem et, laoreet massa. Nulla ornare augue velit, non placerat nulla pretium et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non rutrum neque, ac ultrices sapien. Etiam lacinia libero vitae dolor ullamcorper laoreet. Ph sellus at auctor leo. Sed blandit urna non justo ornare blandit.</p>
                <p class="toggle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget vestibulum augue. Pellentesque suscipit tellus quis dapibus fermentum. Sed risus lectus, mollis quis orci vitae, mattis consequat sapien. Sed vitae cursus nisi. Suspendisse cursus felis nec felis ornare, sit amet ullamcorper diam dictum. Fusce feugiat pellentesque lorem, at eleifend tellus rutrum sit amet. Vestibulum id neque est. Duis interdum nunc nec lobortis rutrum. Sed ut tincidunt turpis, et adipiscing urna. Nam sit amet tellus et elit fringilla tempus ut vitae erat. Integer eu placerat magna, non ornare felis. Aenean eu dapibus leo. Cras dui nisi, volutpat in pretium vitae, ultrices a dui. Nullam consequat feugiat purus non vehicula. Aenean lacinia, mi non euismod malesuada, lorem dolor scelerisque velit, sed consequat ante leo quis nisl. Etiam vel lacus dolor. Quisque at fringilla eros. Vivamus eget turpis sem. Praesent vel hendrerit ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer scelerisque diam ut justo feugiat, quis porttitor felis imperdiet. Mauris at ullamcorper sem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus ultrices leo vitae lacinia vulputate. Vestibulum orci ligula, imperdiet non luctus eget, luctus eu nisl. Maecenas mollis eleifend sollicitudin. Praesent dictum tristique ipsum, quis imperdiet quam. Praesent euismod velit sed ipsum posuere vulputate. Praesent placerat ipsum sed neque viverra, sed adipiscing tortor pulvinar. Phasellus blandit sit amet ligula quis ultrices. Integer tempus risus sit amet aliquam lacinia. Phasellus nec nibh vitae odio tristique commodo. Proin mollis iaculis sapien, a vestibulum odio tincidunt facilisis. Vestibulum sed nibh ornare, mattis ligula quis, porttitor magna. Duis interdum mattis mauris, vel molestie massa porta sit amet. Maecenas vel urna et nisl sodales volutpat non sed urna. Nam dui tortor, semper sed dictum non, congue quis leo. Aenean vitae mi bibendum, sollicitudin sem et, laoreet massa. Nulla ornare augue velit, non placerat nulla pretium et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non rutrum neque, ac ultrices sapien. Etiam lacinia libero vitae dolor ullamcorper laoreet. Ph sellus at auctor leo. Sed blandit urna non justo ornare blandit.</p>
                <p class="toggle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget vestibulum augue. Pellentesque suscipit tellus quis dapibus fermentum. Sed risus lectus, mollis quis orci vitae, mattis consequat sapien. Sed vitae cursus nisi. Suspendisse cursus felis nec felis ornare, sit amet ullamcorper diam dictum. Fusce feugiat pellentesque lorem, at eleifend tellus rutrum sit amet. Vestibulum id neque est. Duis interdum nunc nec lobortis rutrum. Sed ut tincidunt turpis, et adipiscing urna. Nam sit amet tellus et elit fringilla tempus ut vitae erat. Integer eu placerat magna, non ornare felis. Aenean eu dapibus leo. Cras dui nisi, volutpat in pretium vitae, ultrices a dui. Nullam consequat feugiat purus non vehicula. Aenean lacinia, mi non euismod malesuada, lorem dolor scelerisque velit, sed consequat ante leo quis nisl. Etiam vel lacus dolor. Quisque at fringilla eros. Vivamus eget turpis sem. Praesent vel hendrerit ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer scelerisque diam ut justo feugiat, quis porttitor felis imperdiet. Mauris at ullamcorper sem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus ultrices leo vitae lacinia vulputate. Vestibulum orci ligula, imperdiet non luctus eget, luctus eu nisl. Maecenas mollis eleifend sollicitudin. Praesent dictum tristique ipsum, quis imperdiet quam. Praesent euismod velit sed ipsum posuere vulputate. Praesent placerat ipsum sed neque viverra, sed adipiscing tortor pulvinar. Phasellus blandit sit amet ligula quis ultrices. Integer tempus risus sit amet aliquam lacinia. Phasellus nec nibh vitae odio tristique commodo. Proin mollis iaculis sapien, a vestibulum odio tincidunt facilisis. Vestibulum sed nibh ornare, mattis ligula quis, porttitor magna. Duis interdum mattis mauris, vel molestie massa porta sit amet. Maecenas vel urna et nisl sodales volutpat non sed urna. Nam dui tortor, semper sed dictum non, congue quis leo. Aenean vitae mi bibendum, sollicitudin sem et, laoreet massa. Nulla ornare augue velit, non placerat nulla pretium et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non rutrum neque, ac ultrices sapien. Etiam lacinia libero vitae dolor ullamcorper laoreet. Ph sellus at auctor leo. Sed blandit urna non justo ornare blandit.</p>
                <p class="toggle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget vestibulum augue. Pellentesque suscipit tellus quis dapibus fermentum. Sed risus lectus, mollis quis orci vitae, mattis consequat sapien. Sed vitae cursus nisi. Suspendisse cursus felis nec felis ornare, sit amet ullamcorper diam dictum. Fusce feugiat pellentesque lorem, at eleifend tellus rutrum sit amet. Vestibulum id neque est. Duis interdum nunc nec lobortis rutrum. Sed ut tincidunt turpis, et adipiscing urna. Nam sit amet tellus et elit fringilla tempus ut vitae erat. Integer eu placerat magna, non ornare felis. Aenean eu dapibus leo. Cras dui nisi, volutpat in pretium vitae, ultrices a dui. Nullam consequat feugiat purus non vehicula. Aenean lacinia, mi non euismod malesuada, lorem dolor scelerisque velit, sed consequat ante leo quis nisl. Etiam vel lacus dolor. Quisque at fringilla eros. Vivamus eget turpis sem. Praesent vel hendrerit ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer scelerisque diam ut justo feugiat, quis porttitor felis imperdiet. Mauris at ullamcorper sem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus ultrices leo vitae lacinia vulputate. Vestibulum orci ligula, imperdiet non luctus eget, luctus eu nisl. Maecenas mollis eleifend sollicitudin. Praesent dictum tristique ipsum, quis imperdiet quam. Praesent euismod velit sed ipsum posuere vulputate. Praesent placerat ipsum sed neque viverra, sed adipiscing tortor pulvinar. Phasellus blandit sit amet ligula quis ultrices. Integer tempus risus sit amet aliquam lacinia. Phasellus nec nibh vitae odio tristique commodo. Proin mollis iaculis sapien, a vestibulum odio tincidunt facilisis. Vestibulum sed nibh ornare, mattis ligula quis, porttitor magna. Duis interdum mattis mauris, vel molestie massa porta sit amet. Maecenas vel urna et nisl sodales volutpat non sed urna. Nam dui tortor, semper sed dictum non, congue quis leo. Aenean vitae mi bibendum, sollicitudin sem et, laoreet massa. Nulla ornare augue velit, non placerat nulla pretium et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non rutrum neque, ac ultrices sapien. Etiam lacinia libero vitae dolor ullamcorper laoreet. Ph sellus at auctor leo. Sed blandit urna non justo ornare blandit.</p>
            </div>
            <footer>bottom-sticky footer</footer>
        </div>
    </body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DFYCK8trfrIXD4bW8NPS

The thing is that it works perfectly in Chrome (46.0.2490.86 m) and Firefox (42.0) on my Windows 8 machine, but not on my iPad (both Safari and Chrome, although they behave differently). I'm almost certain that it doesn't work in Safari on Max OS X as well. I've tried a couple of different approaches, but it always works on my machine, but not on Apple devices. As you can see I've already done away with the `height: 100vh;` which seems to be a bit buggy on Apple's software.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. The inner `#content` needed to be set up like this:

```
#content {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```